# How to copy Text from one Word Document to another Word Document using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, copy-paste

I want to copy one word document to another word document dynamically. This process can be done in Button Click. Document (docs) contains text, I want to copy it to document (docs2)

```
public void ReadMsWord()
    {
        string filePath = null;
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.Title = "Word File";
        file.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        file.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filePath = file.FileName.ToString();
        }
        try
        {
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application Oword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            //Oword.Visible = true;
            var templatepath = filePath;
            var wordapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            var orgnldoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(templatepath);
            orgnldoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            orgnldoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            var newdcmnt=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            newdcmnt.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
            newdcmnt.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\Documents\TestDoc2.docx");
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordapp);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(orgnldoc);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newdcmnt);
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question We all have our wants and needs but I do not see a question here

Comment: What is the error? what did you try?

Comment: No overload for method 'PasteSpecial' takes 1 argument

Comment: can you also show what the full path looks like for your `filePath` variable..?

Comment: i am using openfiledialog..,

Comment: I will post an example when using the OpenFileDialog to save the Word doc

Comment: Openfiledialog is not for saving is for opening a Word Document

Comment: can you post the all the code that pertains to the portion of code when you are wanting to `Save that Doc to another Doc`

Comment: Since "No overload for method 'PasteSpecial' takes 1 argument", have you tried looking up the documentation on that function?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.pastespecial%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: I am testing something real quick and I will post you a working solution what version of Office are you using..? also are you familiar with `name space Aliasing`? If not I will show you also what you need to change your `using` statement at the .cs file header to

Comment: ok i will wait for your posting..,

Comment: Hey had to reboot my machine I have scaled down a simpler version that you can test.. if you need to make this a method you can use vs2010 to extract this into a Method you as well.. if not I will post that as well.. let me know if you have any other questions or issues

Comment: Alter the method and right after you call OpenFileDialog you could use the `System.IO.Path() method to extract only the file name and also pass to the method your new file name if you need help setting up the Method structure just let one know

Comment: i am using vs2008...,

Comment: This should still work.. you need to make sure that you reference the correct Version when you add the reference to `Microsoft.Interop.Word` this code works on all version and Visual Studio 2008 should allow for namespace aliasing you will need to test that since I don't have that one on my current machine I do however have it at home which of course I am not home..have you tested the code.. it works well on my end..

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I have tested Make sure that you do not stop the debugger until you have gotten to the `Marshal.Release code and GC.Collect`

I have office 2010 but in your using section add the following

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

this is how you implement `namespace Aliasing`

here is the code below

```
var fileName = "TestDoc.docx";
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
var oTemplatePath = @"C:\Documents\wrkDocuments\" + fileName;
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
var originalDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@oTemplatePath);

originalDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
originalDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

var newDocument = new Word.Document();
newDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
newDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\Documents\wrkDocuments\TestDoc2.docx");
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(originalDoc);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newDocument);
GC.Collect();
```

Alter this Method that I have created for you and pass in the proper params

```
private static void CopyWordDoc()
{
    var fileName = "TestDoc.docx";
    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    var oTemplatePath = @"C:\Documents\wrkDocuments\" + fileName;
    var wordApp = new Word.Application();
    var originalDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@oTemplatePath);
    // you can do the line above by passing ReadOnly=False like this as well
    //var originalDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@oTemplatePath, oMissing, false);
    originalDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
    originalDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

    var newDocument = new Word.Document();
    newDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
    newDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\Documents\wrkDocuments\TestDoc2.docx");
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(originalDoc);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newDocument);
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: it is not working it gives error No overload for method 'SaveAs' & 'Open' &'takes '1' arguments

Comment: What version of Word are you using..? also what Assembly are you adding to your reference..? I am referencing `ver 14.0` can you please show me the using section of your file as well as the updated code that you are using.. this works I just need to know the version you're using so that I can add the assembly and test it..

Comment: please show me the code you can edit your original post to show that..I need to see what you are doing

Comment: I reference ver 12.0 and I am getting no errors so i am not sure what you are doing but I have an idea..if you would please post what has been requested I would be able to help. I have version `14.0` I removed the reference and added a reference to `12.0` and the code still works.

Comment: Please show me the using section at the top also are you right clicking on reference=> then adding the correct assembly it should be `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` you should see that under the project->refrence section. I see that you did not follow the example quite as I have suggested..there is a reason for Aliasing the namespace it's to `Avoid` `Method name Collision` for example winforms has a `Application` key word so does `Microsoft` so in order to resolve to the correct Method I use `Aliasing`

Comment: Also are you grabbing the Wod document when using the opendialog..? I would be much easier to hard code the values for test purposes first then once you get that working replace it with the parameters